# How to set ":make" to use scons?

Tags: vim, scons

I know there is a way to make vim run `scons` instead of `make` when I press `:make`.

I had an option that did this in my `~/.vimrc` but I removed it a while ago and forgot what it was.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set [`makeprg`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27makeprg%27).  I'm not sure if any options are required for `scons`, but it might look like:

```
set makeprg=scons
```

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem this weekend. I didn't want to type `:set makeprg=scons` every time I started Vim or hard-code `'makeprg'` in my `.vimrc`, because I use `make` for some projects, `maven` for others, `rake`..., *et cetera* ...

So today I wrote a Vim plugin called [**Makeshift**](https://github.com/johnsyweb/vim-makeshift) to determine what to call for `:make` by looking for known files (`Makefile`, `SConstruct`, `pom.xml`, ...) and setting `'makeprg'` accordingly.

Details are on [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4278) for [DoR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/140814/dor) and future visitors to this question.

Comment: @Sardathrion: I'm delighted you have found it useful.